# Accessing variable from Chrome dev tools (js namespacing)

Tags: javascript, namespaces, meteor

I am doing a tutorial on Meteor and very early on I run into an issue accessing the variable "lists" from my dev tools console (also happens in Firefox).

Apparently Meteor wraps the main js file in an anonymous self-instantiating function, which is cool because otherwise I'd probably done that myself, but it seems that I cannot access the properties of this function from the browser unless I pause the code before the function is finished.

I am really early on in the tutorial, so I basically just set up a new project and added in a collection, but cannot access it to start filling in any demo data. The following screenshot should outline the problem. If I place a breakpoint at line 22 I will be able to access the collection.

I experienced the same issue on another project recently, even though it works when I look at other peoples projects where they seem to be doing the same, so maybe there is just some minor detail I'm missing?

[image]

(If you're interested I'm working off the very first tutorial in the book "Getting Started With Meteor" by Isaac Strack. This exact code works in his book, btw)

Comment: "Apparently Meteor wraps the main js file in an anonymous self-instantiating function, which is cool because otherwise I'd probably done that myself, but it seems that I cannot access the properties of this function from the browser unless I pause the code before the function is finished." - That's how IIFEs work. If you wrapped the code in an IIFE yourself, you wouldn't be able to access the variable from the console. If you want it to be a global, you can define it without `var`. The better option is just to place a breakpoint like you already figured out!

Comment: Thanks, I have a better understanding of IIFEs now. Can't believe I did not think about dropping the var statement; that's the easiest way to get it available in the console, although it is pretty hacky.

Comment: Well, it's really only hacky if you don't want it to be a global variable. That is the documented method of defining a global scoped (or rather, package/app scope) variable in Meteor. It's necessary if you want to share the variable between files. If you want it to feel more explicit, you can do something like `(function( global ) { global.myVar = "foo"; })( this );`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why would you expect to access the `lists` in the way you tried in the console?

When the encapsulating function (the one that wraps the code) exits, `lists` is not available to you in any way - it is in all other wrapped functions **closure**, so their code can access it, which should be the whole purpose.

It is however, "hidden" from the "outer" world - to any code that is not in the same scope, which is in this case is the scope of the wrapping function.

Placing breakpoint at line 22 stops the execution and "lets you" into the wrapping function scope, which is why you can see `lists` in that case.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The reason I expected it to work was simply that it seems to work in the book I am following and I expect the author to know his js better than I do :) Additionally I don't seem to recall anyone having to either pause the execution or add collections to global namespaces in order to manipulate the DB in any of the tutorial videos I've seen. But logically it makes perfect sense that I can't access the variable. What would you consider the "right" way to do it, if you need to access variables from the console?

Comment: Use debugger :) In some cases authors like to simplify things just for the sake of the explanation, so may be it was just poorly worded?

Answer (score 2):

You could set a `window` property in your function to get access at any point.

```
var lists = yadayadayada;
window.lists = lists;
```

Then you'll be able to see `lists` in the dev tools console.

Comment: I don't know why would you do that. Debugging tools are there for a reason.

Comment: I tried doing the above for a "hacky" solution (after all this is not production code), but the window variable causes meteor to crash (after all it is not part of the js spec, but a browser feature as far as I remember). The solution was to either use the debugger or hack it by removing var, making the variable global.

Comment: @funkylaundry Yes `window` is not available on Node.js. The Node.js global variable is called `global`. In either case, `this` refers to the global variable, as long as you are not in a strict-mode function or an object method.